# How do I solve problems sending mail phpmailer slow?

Tags: email, ssl, phpmailer

Hello mails sent by phpmailer very quickly after receiving the e-mail before sending ssl SSL on my site takes about 50 seconds.

I also apply it to another subject suggested the following procedure, but it did not work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23561796/7045282

Debug the output of decision is as follows.

```
Connection: opening to mail.skynetmedya.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-tr1.internetbilisim.net ESMTP Exim 4.86_1 #1 Thu, 20 Oct 2016 04:29:23 +0300 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.skynetmedya.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-tr1.internetbilisim.net Hello www.skynetmedya.com [31.192.209.89]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.skynetmedya.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-tr1.internetbilisim.net Hello www.skynetmedya.com [31.192.209.89]250-SIZE 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: xxx==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<gokhan6116@gmail.com>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<info@skynetmedya.com>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 01:28:30 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Skynet Medya <info@skynetmedya.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: =?UTF-8?Q?G=C3=B6khan_Atalay?= <gokhan6116@gmail.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Skynet_Medya_=C4=B0leti=C5=9Fim_Formu?=
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <4716b9919628d0b8ae2683fba1eb31ab@www.skynetmedya.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.16 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <style>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: td{border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid #dedede;}</style>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <table width="735" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td colspan="4" style="background:black;color:white" align="center">Skynet Medya İletişim Formu</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="145">Ad Soyad:</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="210">Gökhan Atalay</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="215">Email</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td width="145">gokhan6116@gmail.com</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <tr>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td>Mesaj</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: <td colspan="3">asdasdasd</td>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: </tr>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: </table>
CLIENT -> SERVER: 
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK id=1bx2Ae-0013wz-6P
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 tr1.internetbilisim.net closing connection
Connection: closed
{"status":"OK", "message":"Mesaj başarıyla gönderildi"}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for asking better received questions. This doesn't look like a programming problem at the moment, more a server problem. If you are writing a program please provide some more details what you wrote. Otherwise this is a question for another stack site superuser.com

Comment: It doesn't help that you removed the timestamps from the debug output so we can't see what's taking the time. Generally, remote, authenticated SMTP is slow. If you want to go fast, send via SMTP to localhost (without auth) and let your local mail server deal with delays, retries and relay authentication, leaving your web pages free to get on with other things.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to that shared SSL Hosting mailer was getting late hit. I wrote tr1.internetbilisim.net issue was fixed as the host.